# How may I insert an image from my Github repository in my Google Colab notebook?

Tags: github, google-colaboratory

I have an image in my Github repository that I would like to upload and include as a Text Cell in my Google Colab Notebook.
I am using the following command:

`![picture](https://github.com/ivonnics/Machine-Learning/blob/master/Tabla%20Confussion%20Matrix.png)`

But what I get is the following:

[image: picture]

Is anyone aware of a solution or alternative to directly upload the requested image FROM MY GITHUB into my Notebook without intermediate steps?
Thanking you in advance...

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to Github
2. Go to your Image
3. Copy the URL
4. Convert the URL in two steps:
   a. Change: **/github.com/** to **raw.githubusercontent.com**
   b. Remove "**/blob/**" from the URL
5. Now in Colab's Text paste the edited URL inside the format:

   You will get an image displayed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change from

```
github.com
```

To

```
raw.githubusercontent.com
```

So, your image would be

```
![](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ivonnics/Machine-Learning/master/Tabla%20Confussion%20Matrix.png)
```

As displayed here.

[image]

Comment: **Thank you very much! Great Solution...** You have to remove also the /blob after the subdirectory specification...

Answer (score 2):

Try using !wget https://your.link.png to download the file, and then use the picture code like you showed above.

Comment: **Thank you so much!**, I learnt how to directly upload a file from Github with your suggestion, and it is also a valid solution. It`s not a single liner as the one above, but it also works, so I am voting for this one too...

Answer (score 1):

What worked for me:

1. Go to GitHub (to the place where the image is).
2. Click on the image with the right button.
3. Select 'Copy Image Address'.
4. Go to your Google Colab notebook.
5. Write `![]({link})`, where {link} is the image address you copied in Step 3 (you can just paste the link).